# Handle the instant before use Window.ShowDialog in .NET

Tags: .net, events, showdialog

Is there any event that handle the instant before a new window is shown?

Is for make a nice fade effect with that script:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?542669-Nice-fading-in-and-out-form-effect

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: In the sample they use Form_Load. This event is raised before showing the form. Have you tried it?

Comment: As long as you initialize the opacity properly, you don't care about the exact time you get the event.

Comment: Please note 'nice' is subjective.